# running a shell script from html

Tags: html, linux, shell

I have created two virtual machines having ubuntu 12.04 lts os. Installed apache tomcat 7 on both VM's (virtual machine). configured virtual private network.

HTTP request on VM1 should run a shell script on VM2 and return the result to VM1 as an html file. I did the configuration part.

Now i need to know, how to write an HTML response file in VM2 server(which can be displayed on VM1 browser as a response) which will invoke a shell script having "ps -Aef" command to list all processes running on VM2.  i need to display the contents of this file on VM1.
since i am a beginner in web programming/shell scripting please help me.
Thank you in advance 
-Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP

1. Install php (`apt-get install php`)
2. copy index.php file into `/var/www/html` folder

index.php

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('ps -Aef');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

browse `http://<ip-address>/index.php`

Comment: hi Kasun, thanks a lot for your guidance. it is working for me. now i am looking for 'ssh' logging in to second machine and execute the same command. i tried $output = shell_exec('ssh ahegde@192.168.162.130 ps -Aef');. but it is not working!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a web server that can run CGI scripts. It's too long to completely list the steps of setting up CGI (and it depends on your web server of choice etc.). But considering you are a beginner, there is a pretty extensive tutorial with examples on how to configure Apache to run CGI scripts [right here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html).

To summarize:

1. You need to install Apache (`apt-get install apache2`)
2. Configure Apache to enable mod_cgi [as described in the tutorial above](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html).
3. Write your first CGI program and test it (also in that tutorial).